# Facebook like and comment box: like count is increasing automatically

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am including Facebook 'like button' and 'comment box' on every page of my website. Website is in testing phase.

**Problem 1:** When I comment on any page, it is not being displayed when I logout of facebook and refresh the same page. As soon as login again into Facebook, my comments are visible to me. That means other people can't see my comments.

**Problem 2:** Along with the above problem, when I comment on a page, it automatically increases the 'like button' count by 1. Suppose I enter 2 comments, then the count is increased by 2.

Is anyone able to identify the problem here? Please help.

Note: I have included the FB Javascript SDK code just after opening the  tag (as per their guidelines)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your first problem; it might have something to do with the settings of your Comment box. In case you haven't done it yet, you should go to the [Facebook Developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/) and get an App ID for the box, so as you can easily change its settings and moderate comments.

As for your second problem, that's an intended behaviour. As it says in the [Like button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> What makes up the number shown on my Like button?
>
> The number shown is the sum of:
>
> - The number of likes of this URL
> - The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
> - The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL